# Secured SSL connection Error: unknown protocol | bad hostname lookup

Tags: c++, http, openssl

Iam downloading RSS feed file (eg. https://tools.ietf.org/dailydose/dailydose_atom.xml) from server via HTTP.

First, i have to connect to the remote server via OpenSSL, as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-openssl/).

---

Unsecured version works just fine and i can connect and receive HTTP answer with feeds:

```
bio = BIO_new_connect("www.tools.ietf.org:80");
if(bio == NULL)
{
    /* Handle the failure */
}

if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
{
    /* Handle failed connection */
}
```

---

Secured version:

```
BIO                 * m_bio;
SSL_CTX             * m_ctx;
SSL                 * m_ssl;

SSL_library_init(); 

m_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(m_ctx);

m_bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(m_ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(m_bio, &m_ssl);
SSL_set_mode(m_ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(m_bio, "www.tools.ietf.org:80");


if (BIO_do_connect(m_bio) <= 0)
{
    printf("Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
    throw std::runtime_error("FEEDREADER: Connection failed.");
}

if(SSL_get_verify_result(m_ssl) != X509_V_OK)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("FEEDREADER: Verification failed.");
}
```

Where `do_connect` fails with following error:

> Error: unknown protocol

when i replace `www.tools.ietf.org` with `http(s)://www.tools.ietf.org`

another error appears:

> Error: bad hostname lookup

But hostname & dns works well for unsecured version, so may somebody help me with this one ?

Comment: In [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_new_ssl_connect.html) they use `ERR_load_crypto_strings(); ERR_load_SSL_strings();` instead of `SSL_load_error_strings(); `ERR_load_BIO_strings();`.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Pretty sure that's supposed to be port 443. Changing the port delivers the proper connection with no errors (that I can see, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

80 is the default HTTP port.  443 is the default HTTPS port.

```
bio = BIO_new_connect("www.tools.ietf.org:443");
```

```
BIO_set_conn_hostname(m_bio, "www.tools.ietf.org:443");
```